# How to update subdocument value through mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update the value of a nested document through a PUT request. It is working for values in the document, but not in the subdocument.

```
const AnotherSchema = new Schema ({
    Name: String,
    Age: Number,
    Appearance: {
       Hair: String, Eyes: String, Height: Number};
```

My route looks like this

```
 router.put("/looks/:id/edit", function(req, res) {
    var Name= "blob"; 
    var Hair= "blue";
    AnotherSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {Name, Hair}, function(err, feedback){
        if (err){
        res.send("error");
        } else {
        res.redirect("/looks");
        }
        });
    });
```

This route works for updating Name, but not Hair. I have tried `Appearance.Hair`, but this throws an error in the console for an unexpected `.` I have also tried `[]`, `()` and `{}` but none of these do the trick, nor do `" "` and this issue does not seem to appear in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be providing the paths via the object notation to the props you want to update:

```
router.put("/looks/:id/edit", function(req, res) {
  AnotherSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
    Name: "blob",
    Appearance: {
      Hair: "blue"
    }
  }, function(err, feedback) {
    if (err) {
      res.send("error");
    } else {
      res.redirect("/looks");
    }
  });
});
```

The above `findByIdAndUpdate` is equivalent to:

`{ $set: { Name: "blob", Appearance: { Hair: "blue" } } }` [as per the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)

Comment: Gotcha, cheers. And if I may ask, in my actual application I want to access a variable from the document in order to add to it, say oldHeight + growth to then save that as Height. In this syntax that you have provided how would you approach that?

Comment: With this approach you do not have access to the old value unless you already got it. If you want to get access to the actual doc values look into the `$where` operator

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `$set` operator, otherwise you will replace the whole record with the object provided as argument.

```
var updateObj = {
  { $set: { Name: "blob", Appearance: { Hair: "blue" } } }
};

AnotherSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, updateObj, function (err, feedback) { ... });
```

Comment: Having run my code above it didn't replace the whole record with the arguments provided, not sure why. Anyway how would I be able to update a document with this syntax though?